# how to activate virtualenv in vs code editor when i type source env/bin/activate it does not activate

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Note: I have newly installed vs code in window 10

```
PS C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Kiit Project\django-ecommerce> source env/bin/activate
source : The term 'source' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the 
name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
+ source env/bin/activate
+ ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (source:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with VS Code. `source` is a Unix shell command. You are running Windows. You should be running the `activate.bat` script.

Comment: i don't know how to run

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the name of your virtual environment is `env`, you can simply go into the directory(I think *C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Kiit Project\django-ecommerce* in your case) where it is and run `env\Scripts\activate`. This should do the work.

However, in VScode you  might have to edit the `settings.json` file present in `.vscode` folder and add the following:

```
{
    ...
    "python.pythonPath": "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Kiit Project\django-ecommerce\env\bin\python",
    ...
}
```

If you are not able to find the `settings.json` file mentioned above, simply press `Ctrl+Shift+P` and type `python Select Interpreter` and press `Enter`. You will then see a `.vscode` directory containing your `settings.json` file.

You can edit this file however you'd like to change the Python interpreter to be used for VScode instance.

Answer (score 0):

I just spent 10 minutes on this as the solution listed did not work. You don't need to add any paths to work this out for VS Code. Here are the steps I took to create and activate the virtual environment in case some one else is looking for this...

**Step 1 - Create the virtual environment:**

```
python -m venv virt
```

Note - the name of my environment here is "virt"

**Step 2 - Activate the virtual environment:**

```
virt\Scripts\Activate.ps1
```

Note - Do not change directories; the path is relative to the location from which you created the environment.

Final note - if the command is successful, you should have a ("""name""") prefix as shown below:
[image: Python virtual environment for Django.]

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using a Windows machine. The commands you are executing are for Linux.

For windows type

```bash
env\bin\activate
```

make sure to use the backward slash `\` in your path and not the forward slash `/`
and it should be good to go.